# Run certain Tox commands only on TravisCI

Tags: python, travis-ci, tox

I am trying to make it so that a code coverage command is only run in Tox for TravisCI. How would I do that?

The codecov library does not work if I just stick it into the `.travis.yml` file, and I want it to not be run during normal tox tests as it makes the console way too messy.

Answer (score 2):

check for the presence of `$TRAVIS` environment variable, see [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables) for others that Travis sets

maybe you need to add this line to your `tox.ini` :

```
passenv = TRAVIS
```

or

you can create a custom entry in your `tox.ini`

```
[testenv:travis]
deps= ...
commands= <your travis command>
```

if you need need to add a step

```
[testenv]
commands =
   ....
   travis: <your travis command>
```

if you need only to change dependencies change  your `deps` as

```
[testenv]
deps =
   travis: <your travis dependencies>
```

in your `travis.ini` call `tox -e travis`

**Note** do not list `travis` in your `envlist=`

one more option if you need to add a step to a matrix

```
[testenv]
passenv = TRAVIS
commands =
  - ...
  - sh -c 'if [ '{env:TRAVIS:}' = 'true' ]; then ...... ; fi'
```

Comment: I know that you can pass the `$TRAVIS` env variable, but how do I use it to modify tox's actions (without writing a custom python script to handle it)?

Comment: I've had difficulties with the symbols used in these kind of "complex" shell commands in tox.ini. You may want to put them into a shell script, or better yet, a Python script.